# Flutter Element LifeCycle

Tags: flutter

I am some confused about the LifeCycle of the Elements objects in Flutter. specifically the creation and mounted of the element, i am not sure about which is the correct process (i only consider StatelessWidgets for simplicity):

1. The framework adds the widget to widget tree (build method not fired yet) then run createElement method. The element is mounted and inserted in the element tree, then the element calls the build method to get the widget subtree or children returned by the build method to later create the correspoding element subtree and inflate it with the corresponding child (widget) configuration. The process repeats iteratively.
2. The framework adds the widget to widget tree, then call build method of this widget and then a element is created with that widget configuration, after the element is mounted and inserted to the Element tree, then the element inflates any child widgets returned by the build method (previously executed) and then create the element subtree corresponding. The process repeats iteratively.

i dont know which of the options are the correct or maybe both are wrong, if someone can get me out of this doubt i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Among the two options you provided, the second one is closer.

1. The framework adds the widget to the widget tree
2. The framework calls the build method of the widget to obtain a widget subtree (child widgets) to be displayed
3. An Element is created for the widget with its configuration. This is done by calling the createElement method of the widget's corresponding StatelessElement class. The Element holds the configuration of the widget and manages the widget's lifecycle
4. The Element is mounted, which means it's inserted into the Element tree
5. The Element's build method is called. This method generates the widget subtree (child widgets) by invoking the build methods of child widgets
6. For each child widget returned by the build method, a new child Element is created (following the same process of creating Elements). This process is recursive and happens for the entire widget subtree
7. The child Elements are mounted in the Element tree as part of their parent Element
8. The layout and rendering process then take place, rendering the widgets on the screen.

Elements can be thought of as a parallel process to the creation and rendering of widgets. Elements handle the management of the widget tree and the corresponding lifecycle events.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response it helps me a lot to understand better the lifecycle process. However i still have some question:
1. Who call the createElement method ?, i understand that is called after StatelessWidget.build
2.  For the StatefulWidget case, the State have the build method, and the Element is who creates the State, so in this case the Element must be created before build method call isn't ?
Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: 1. createElement method is not directly called by user code. Instead, it's invoked internally by the framework itself when it's building the widget tree. 
2. Yes, the creation of the element and the associated state happens before the build method is called. This allows the state to manage the widget's mutable state and the corresponding UI representation. Welcome :)